# Schengen: First entry to visa issued country. Leave for other Schengen 1 hour later?

Tags: visas, schengen

Would it be any problem if I would enter the country first where I got a single entry visa from and then 1 hour later, leave for another Schengen country by plane?

I already booked a hotel in this first entry country which shows it will be the longest stay.

But I could change my mind and maybe stay longer in the other country, where I will travel 1 hour after I enter this first entry country.

As I am unemployed, could this raise suspicion by the border agent?
Or it won't be a problem if I show a ticket that shows I will be traveling 2 days later back to this first entry country and then stay there for the most of the stay?

Again, I could decide to stay in this second Schengen country and travel back home from there and decide not to use the return ticket to the first entry country.

I just don't want any trouble, I'm already glad I got a Schengen visa, so any tips would be welcome :)

Comment: If you don't know your own plans, how can we possibly aid you?

Comment: @CGCampbell he is probably trying to sound legal whereas the intent is to work in the second country, I only say probably because I am not ure either :P

Comment: I don’t intend to work in the other country, I have enough money as provided in the documents for the visa itself. Unemployed doesn’t right away mean poor or looking for work.

I got the Visa and planned to visit one specific country only to hear my friends from the States are visiting Europe, so it would be much more fun to hang out.
Thus this means my primary first entry point will not be visited for more then 30 minutes.

I just don’t want to have any troubles because of this for future Visa requests, hence the question what to do best to be safe,but still visit the other countries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to travel through several Schengen countries, you are supposed to apply for a visa from the *main* destination of your trip. The main destination is not necessarily the first country you enter. The main destination is *probably* the country where you spend the most time, but there may be exceptions to that. You already have your visa, so obviously the consulate considered itself the relevant authority.

You have submitted travel plans with your visa application. You are allowed to make minor adjustments to your plan. Suppose you want to spend your holiday in France, with short trips to several cities in France, Italy and Germany. Bad weather might cause you to re-schedule the various trips, or even skip some completely.

You will be in trouble if the immigration official **thinks** that you lied during your initial application, or that there was a substantial change in your plans and circumstances since that initial application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your visa is for the entire Schengen zone, and not just the country you have applied for. There can be many restrictions on visas and one of them is that the visa may only be valid for the country issued; it will state this on the very top line of the visa document (stamp on your passport).

Your very first challenge will be crossing the border of the country that issued you the visa.

As you probably know, a visa is not a guarantee of entry into the country, its just a permit to travel and request entry. It is up to the immigration officer to allow you into the country.

You should be prepared to show documents (the same ones that you used for the initial visa application) at the immigration counter.

Now - assuming your visa is for the entire zone; and you were granted entry into Country A; you can collect your bags and board a flight for Country B (that is in the Schengen zone) without issue - you don't even need to leave the airport!

There are no border controls, as flying within the Schengen zone is akin to flying domestically.

You can also choose to exit the Schengen zone from any member state. Your passport will be stamped by the immigration officer upon your exit.

Comment: The only problem is that my situation changed.
I would stay the longest in the first entry country, but I got a message from friends in the States, they are visiting Europe in that same time frame.

As I don’t want to have any troubles at the passport check, would the following be wise:

1) Enter first entry country thought passport check (As the original plan)
2) Collect bags
3) Check in bags to flight to other Schengen country

At 3, if questions are asked, show them that the ticket for this flight as a return trip in 2 days. Which means I will still stay the most days in the entry country.

Comment: Normally, you'd have no difficulty at all, in fact, no questions asked at 3. Due to recent events, however, there is a bit more likely-hood you may be profiled (depending on your country of origin and previous recent travels) and/or questions could be asked by authorities that wouldn't normally occur. As they are new, possibly temporary and random, we can't really answer with 100% certainty you won't have any problems at all. We can only state you _shouldn't normally_.